# How to Sequentially batch sas codes in queue?

Tags: batch-jobs

I have couple of SAS jobs that I need to run sequentially and some in parallel.

I typically type in nohup sas filename1.sas & in the command line to run and manually check for progress every few hours. If the 1st job is complete and no error, I then type in the 2nd job nohup sas filename2.sas & .

Is there a sas code or unix command I can run them sequentially rather than manually checking progress?

I thought about using %include statement in a master sas file, however it takes very long to execute them in that way (way more than what it takes when i do the checking manually).

Note:If at the end of execution of codes if th output says 'Done' or 'Done(1)' the job is considered to be successfully run.I also need the log and lst file to be printed for each individual job

Comment: If I understand right, what you want to do is to run several commands if the previous one is executed correctly. In that case you can use &&. For example "command 1 && command 2 && ... && command N". That way command 3 will be executed only if command 2 has been executed successfully. But not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: yea..that was what i was looking for..but to be clear it will be like :           nohup sas filnename1.sas && filnename2.sas && ....filenameN.sas &                   right? Also i have to run some codes paralelly in between so that i can save some time..any recomendations?